# How to check if the installed Windows version supports UWP (or DCH) using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, uwp

I was looking into what versions of Windows support DCH drivers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/dch-principles-best-practices). The page seems to suggest that any "UWP-based edition of Windows" supports DCH.

While I know this means that Windows 10 and newer support it, is there a PowerShell command that can be ran on most versions of Windows to output whether UWP (or DCH) is supported?

Comment: While this isn't 100% future-proof, it's the simplest way to just see if it's a newer OS `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -Property BuildNumber).BuildNumber -ge 10240`

Comment: @CrookedJ `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).BuildNumber -ge 10240` works, too.

Comment: yes it will, I just specified the property as it is (slightly) more efficient to only return a single property